# Uppercase and lowercase search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a search engine for my jsgrid, but I ran into a problem. How to search uppercase and lowercase text?

Because now, I only get results if I use the same symbols.

```
loadData: function (filter) {
  var ajaxItemsFiltered = [];
  $.each(ajaxItems, function (index, value) {
    var allow = true;
    $.each(value, function (index2, value2) {

      if (typeof filter[index2] !== "undefined" && filter[index2] !== '') {

        if (value2.indexOf(filter[index2]) === -1) {

          allow = false;
        }
      }
    });
    if (allow) {
      ajaxItemsFiltered.push(value);
    }
  });


  return ajaxItemsFiltered;
},
```

Comment: change to one case either `Uppercase` or `lowercase` and then match

Comment: `if (value2.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[index2].toLowerCase()) === -1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Intl.Collator to perform case insensitive comparisons

```js
const localeCompare = Intl.Collator('en', { sensitivity: 'base' }).compare;
function includesByIgnoreCase(predicate) {
  if (this.filter(predicate).length > 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};

const value2 = ['hElLo', 'world', 'foo', 'Hello Wolrd'];

console.log(
  includesByIgnoreCase.call(
    value2,
    e => localeCompare(e, 'hello world') !== 0
  )
);
```

References:
MDN: [Intl.Collator.prototype.compare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator/compare)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a sensitive case language so you need to change both compared values to "Upper" or "Lower" case to make the check without worrying about the case sensitivity, like:

```
if (value2.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter[index2].toLowerCase()) === -1)
//OR
if (value2.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter[index2].toUpperCase()) === -1)
```